# Can we get the portfolio size approximation from the PnL?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, performanceanalytics

Im wondering if we can get the portfolio size approximation, if we have the volatility and -/+ pnl of the portfolio ? Is there a method or a formula ?  Example the annual volatility of 3% and daily PnL in range of +/- 10000€ ? Thank you

Comment: Convert the annual volatility to daily and then it becomes fairly easy.

Comment: Once we have the daily vol, how to go from me it to the find the portfolio size? Please help me it’s quite urgent

Comment: 3% a year is 0.03/sqrt(252) = 0.00189 per day. If 10000 EUR is twice the daily standard deviation then the portfolio size is 5000/0.00189 = 2.6 million EUR. Caution: this is very approximate, could easily be off by a factor of 2 or more.

Comment: Oh thank you, this can work if the pnl is a range +/- 10000 ?

Comment: Why did you divide the pnl by 2 ?

Comment: Your lack of knowedge is dangerous, please study these things before you get in trouble.

Comment: I will for sure the problem is that I couldn’t find anywhere or at any book what I am looking for.... this is why I am looking for people to explain to me if you have a book or site where I can read more about it I would love too

Comment: @Gogo78, Can you compute $x$, If $x_2 \sim\mathcal {N}(x,7),x_1\sim\mathcal{N}(2,5)$ and $\rho_{1,2}=0.7$. If you study these things, you will come to know why 5000 have been divided by 0.00189 and why pnl$\pm10000EUR$ have been divided by 2. $\rho_{1,2}$ means correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$